# Create an Amazon AMI form the Snapshot using .net c# sdk

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, sdk, image.createimage

I can see 2 places from where an image can be created 1. from instance 2. from snapshot

Through .net sdk, i can create the image from option 1 but could not find a way to crate an image from the snapshot using sdk. Do someone have any idea about this?

CreateImageRequest ask mandatory parameter intance id. I just wanted to create image from Snapshot using .net sdk c# as we can do it from AWS console.

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is always a good idea to add some code, so that the community knows what your already have worked on and can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

To create an image from a snapshot you need to use the `RegisterImage` or `RegisterImageAsync` method.